# Else statement is being executed where it is not supposed to

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have written a program for school homework. The program takes 3 positive  integers as parameters from standard input and prints if the triangle is Equilateral, Isosceles or Scalene. [Here](http://ideone.com/U97B8z) is the code.

The program is working so far, but not I intended. The line 25

```
System.out.println("Triangle sides should be positive integer ");
```

is supposed to be executed only when negative integers is given. But it is being executed when types other than integers are given. For example when I fed the text file with line "dfd 5 4 6", it is prompting:

Line 5 - dfd: the  side of the triangle should be an integer
Triangle sides should be positive integer

But it is supposed to print the first line only. I have written else statement for floating point number  and strings in main function lines  94 and 105. But it is being executed in addition to else statements. How can I avoid it ?

Comment: Please post your code directly in the question, not as an external link. Furthermore, have you visually verified by printing out or viewing in the debugger that your `a`, `b` and `c` are actually all positive numbers?

Comment: why not create `else if (a < 0 || b < 0 || c < 0){ //print numbers should be positive}` ? and then `else {//do something}` for those that are not numbers.

Comment: This could happen as your `int[]` array would be initialized with zeros initially. Now if you read in a non-integer, the array will stay at zero and the triangle created using a zero.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After execution of `for` loop, `new Triangle(a[0],a[1],a[2]);` will be executed and the `else` block at line 103 will be executed only when `lineText` don't have next line.

To avoid this use a boolean variable and set it true at `else` block at line 94. Now put `if` condition for line 99.

```
boolean areInvalidSides = false;

else { // line 92
    areInvalidSides = true;
    System.out.printf("Line %d - %s: the  side of the triangle should be an integer\n", lineNum, lineText.next());
}

if(!areInvalidSides){
    new Triangle(a[0],a[1],a[2]); // line 99
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think isPositive function should be like below .

```
    boolean isPositive (int a, int b, int c){
    if ((a<0)||(b<0)||(c<0)){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Well, but a triangle side of zero isn't really valid either, even though it's not negative.  (Although I suppose it will fail the inequality check anyway if a value is zero.)  This isn't where the problem lies.

Comment: I tried but the same results. But thank you for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

"I have written else statement for floating point number and strings in main function lines 94 and 105."

Yes, but all you do is print an error message, which does nothing to actually make the user input valid numbers.  If they enter 65.8, you'll print a message and then continue trying to make a triangle with a side missing.  That's obviously not what you want.

Perhaps you should enclose each input request in a `while` loop, checking for valid input and immediately making the user re-enter if they don't enter a valid integer.